# Unable to certain breakpoint in eclipse for a certain file alone

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I try to set a break point anywhere within this particular file, I don't see a breakpoint getting set in spite of clicking multiple times.

Also, the left margin of the window appears white, as opposed to being blue in the files where I am able to set a breakpoint.

[image: Left margin appears white]

When I try to set a break point in the other files, appears blue, and I am able to set a break point.

I have checked that in my break point settings, I am not doing something like Skip All breakpoints

[image: Skip All breakpoints is not selected]

How can I debug the file that is of interest to me?
PS : This file I am trying to set a break point is an implementation of an interface. Adding some extra information, just in case.

Comment: Can you set breakpoints in other source files in the same package? Same folder? Any folder? Other projects? Other than it not working, what have you tried?

Comment: Silly doubt, but is the file in classpath?

Comment: @nitind Yes, other source files in the same package do work. Same folder, other folder, other projects all do work. Just this one doesn't. Actually, I figured out why it doesn't. Want to take a shot at the cause? :)

Comment: I know you mean that in good spirits, but not really.

Comment: @nitind, the file had a build error due to some dependency missing.

Comment: @Timothy, thanks for the reply. It was due to a compilation error, that I was not able to set the breakpoint.